# Why SPFx updated solution is not shown in Edge browser?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-webparts, react

I am using a solution in edge and chrome. The updated solution is shown in chrome and in private window of edge but the updated solution is not shown in the main window of edge.

Can someone please tell that why it is happening and what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Maybe browser cache issue. Try clearing browser cache and cookies (for all time). Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: it works but I have to do this every time when I update the solution , is there any other solution for this?

Comment: It should work after few refreshes (Ctrl + F5) as well without clearing browser cache.

Comment: (Ctrl + F5) is not working. I use this multiple times. Can I clear browser cache through codes?

Comment: Try solutions given here: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+%2B+clear+browser+cache+site:stackoverflow.com. But clearing browser cache each time web part loads may cause any other issue or it may log you out of SharePoint (and/or other site where you are logged in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the question description, I think the issue is with the Microsoft edge browser cache or cookies.

Try below to resolve this issue:

1. Try clearing browser cache and cookies in Microsoft edge browser (for all time)

   **References**:

   1. [Delete cookies in Microsoft Edge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/delete-cookies-in-microsoft-edge-63947406-40ac-c3b8-57b9-2a946a29ae09)
   2. [How to manage and clear your cache and cookies](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/learning-center/how-to-manage-and-clear-your-cache-and-cookies?form=MA13I2)
2. Try hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) on Microsoft edge browser.